# How do you resolve a promise only after the bound expressions are updated?

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angular-promise

My situation is like this:

I've got a template like below, though I've simplified it and kept only the crucial parts.

```
...
<div>
     <div ng-if="status.sidebarLoaded">
          <div id="sidebar">
               <div ng-repeat="menuItem in sidebar.sidebarMenu">
                    <p>{{menuItem}}</p>
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
     <div ng-if="status.mainLoaded">
          <div id="main">
               <div ng-include="'theTemplate'" onload="thing=main.thing">
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="theTemplate.html">
     {{thing}}
</script>
```

In the controller, I've got a chain of promises like this:

```
    getSidebarFromHttp()
        .then(function(){
            $scope.status.sidebarLoaded = true;
            getMainStuff();
        })
        .then(function(){
            $scope.status.mainLoaded = true;
        });
```

Theoretically, this should result in the `sidebar` presented, and the value of `{{thing}}` evaluated. **But `{{thing}}` just stays blank.**

I realized that the reason this isn't working is because `$scope.status.mainLoaded = true;` is executed before the values acquired from `getMainStuff()` are properly bound to the expressions in the template. I discovered this by adding a timeout to the last `.then()`, like so

```
       .then(function(){
            $timeout(function(){
                $scope.status.mainLoaded = true;
            }, 3000);
        }
```

So my question is, How do I set `mainLoaded` to true **only AFTER** all the value is the previous function are bound? Is there a special type of promise that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding callback to your `getMainStuff()`

```
function getMainStuff(callback){
    // DO SOMETHING
    calback();
}
```

and your function call should be like this

```
getSidebarFromHttp()
    .then(function(){
        // callback function to set $scope.status.sidebarLoaded after some method executed
        var callback = function(){
            $scope.status.sidebarLoaded = true;
        }
        // call getMainStuff with callback function as paramter
        getMainStuff(callback);
    })
    .then(function(){
        $scope.status.mainLoaded = true;
    });
```